# VS 2010 build on 32bit and 64 bit (Program Files)

Tags: visual-studio-2010, post, build

I have a VS 2010 Post Build Event that runs `GacUtil.exe`.

On my *32-bit* laptop I reference:

```
"C:\Program Files \Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\bin\gacutil.exe" -i "$(TargetPath)".
```

On my *64-bit* dev server it needs to be

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\bin\gacutil.exe" -i "$(TargetPath)".
```

But I want to check-in a project that works on both systems.

Has anyone figured out how to do a post build event that is architecture independent?

Comment: Why not just add the bin folder to the PATH enviroment variable on both machines?

Comment: Exhibit 9431 why hard-coding directory paths is BAD BAD BAD.

Comment: I think I may need a path that depends on .net version so a path covers my question as asked but I think I need a per project soln. Bad Bad indeed but replace with what?

Answer (score 2):

I call this in the post-build step: [sgen](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bk3w6240%28VS.80%29.aspx).

**Update Visual Studio 2013:**

This command works both on 32- and 64-bit machines:

```
"$(SDK40ToolsPath)$(SGenSubFolder)sgen.exe" /nologo /force /assembly:"$(TargetPath)" /compiler:/platform:$(Platform) /type:"[NameOfTheType]"
```

The `$(SGenSubfolder)` property is defined as

```
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Platform)' == 'x64' ">
  <SGenSubFolder>x64\</SGenSubFolder>
</PropertyGroup>
```

What a mess...

Comment: Note that you should put quotes around `$(TargetPath)`, in case it contains any spaces.

Answer (score 0):

```
for /f "tokens=2,*" %a in ('reg query "HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0a" /v InstallationFolder ^| findstr InstallationFolder') do "%b\bin\Gacutil.exe" -i "$(TargetPath)"
```